# Is SSL enough for protecting a request and its headers?

Tags: authentication, ssl

I ask this because I work on an application where the X-AUTH-TOKEN can be copied from one request to another and impersonate another person. This makes me nervous, but I'm told since we're going to use HTTPS we don't have to worry about anything.

So, my question is: Is it good enough trust SSL to protect against stealing headers used for auth/sessions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTPS standard implements HTTP entirely on top of SSL/TLS. Because of this, practically everything except for the DNS query is encrypted. Since headers are part of the request and response, and only sent after the secure-channel has been created, they are precisely as secure as the implementation of HTTPS on the given server.

Comment: Thanks. I see so I shouldn't worry about the security issue because it will be covered up by HTTPS. I was wondering if it was best to implement best practices for session management along with using HTTPS (IMO if HTTPS wasn't being used this was be a massive security flaw, which is why I nervous) .

Comment: I'm not saying not to worry about it, but that HTTPS does provide a layer of security and guards against types of MIM attacks. Best practices for session management should definitely still be adhered to! :)

Answer (score 2):

Using HTTPS encryption will indeed prevent someone from stealing your authentication token if they can intercept the traffic.  It won't necessarily prevent a man-in-the-middle attack though unless the client enables peer certificate checking.

[This question from the security stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33374/whats-an-easy-way-to-perform-a-man-in-the-middle-attack-on-ssl) describes how to implement MITM attacks against SSL.  If I can convince a client running HTTPS to connect to my server, and *they accept my certificate* then I can steal your authentication token and re-use it.  Peer certificate validation is sometimes a bit of a pain to setup but it can give you a higher chance of whomever you are connecting to are who they say that are.

"Good enough" is a relative definition and depends on your level of paranoia.  Personally I would be happy that my connection is secure enough with HTTPS and peer certificate validation turned on.

Presumably also your authentication token times out so the attack window would be time limited.  For example the OpenStack authentication token is by default valid for 24 hours before it expires and then you are required to obtain a new one.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS is an end-to-end encryption of the entire HTTP session, including the headers, so on the face of it, you should be safe from eavesdropping.

However, that is only part of the story: depending on how the clients are actually connecting (is this a website or an API service?), it may still be possible to trick them into sending the data to the wrong place, for instance:

- Presenting a "man in the middle" site with an invalid SSL certificate (since it won't be from a trusted authority, or won't be for the right domain) but convincing users to by-pass this check. Modern browsers make a big fuss about this kind of thing, but libraries for connecting to APIs might not.
- Presenting a different site / service end-point at a slightly different URL, with a valid SSL certificate, harvesting authentication tokens, and using them to connect to the real service.
- Harvesting the token inside the client application, before it is sent over HTTPS.

No one approach to security is ever sufficient to prevent all attacks. The main consideration should be the trade-off between how complex additional measures would be to implement vs the damage that could be done if an attacker exploited you not doing them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The service is intended to be an api for our html front end or if someone wants to write their own client and use our apis.